# touchesMoved method gets called four to five times and touch gets cancelled

Tags: ios, uitouch

I have implemented touches method inside a view. 
touchesMoved method gets called four to five times and touch gets cancelled automatically.
Can u please tell me the reason for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Touches Moves method called when touch moves on screen. So there are multiple points on the move path. So the touches moves method called multiple times for points which are on the touch move path.

Comment: @ Pradhyuman Chavda:   Touches Ended never gets called and Touches Moved gets cancelled even when i am moving my finger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have added any gesturerecognizer in your class then it will cancelled automatically.This happened to me also. when gestureRecognizer gets recognised then touchCancelled method will be called automatically..

Comment: i have removed all the gestures from that view and controller ,still problem is the same.

Comment: GestureRecogniser cancelsTouchesInView property to NO solved it

Answer (score 0):

TouchesBegan : will be called when touch begins (Gives starting point of touch)
TouchesMoved : will be called when the touch moves(touch the screed and move u r finger)[Give all the touched points between began and end]
TouchesEnd   : will be called when the touch ends.(Gives the Last touch Point)

Comment: Touches Ended never gets called and Touches Moved gets cancelled even when i am moving my finger

Comment: when you didn't add any guesturerecognisers why did u implement that method?